# How to center text in-between navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have been learning htm, css and php all at once. I am creating a website that touch's all of 
these things. Its for educational purposes only.

How can I make it so that I have my websites name beside the navigation text with it all centered.
Like right now I have the website name in the nav bar with the navigation text beside it but the
navigation text isnt in the center of the line its a bit low. Here is the site: `http://66.172.10.179/resolver/`

CSS:

```
/* Body */
body {
    background-color: #FF5930;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

/* Navigation bar */

header {
    background-color: #FF4719;
    padding: 5px 0 8px 15px;
}

header nav h2 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

header nav ul {
    display: inline;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;    
    color: white;
    height: 10px;
}

header nav ul li:hover {

}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <h2><a href="index.php">Skype Resolver</a></h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Resolver</a></li>
            <li><a href="blacklist.php">Blacklisting</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.php">Purchase API</a></li>
            <li><a href="dtools.php">Domain tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="stools.php">Spam tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="mtools.php">Misc tools</a></li>
        </ul>                           
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: have you tried `float`ing the elements or adding `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: one easy way is to add a line-height: 0; to the H2, but that will reduce the height of the nav

Comment: Thanks both users. I used inline-block and line-height. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

I added line-height to H2, create a CSS thing for nav and added: display: inline-block;

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Something to note about inline-block is that is starts to respect whitespace, more here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this without actually putting in any line height you can add the following:

**CSS**

```
nav{
    display:table;
}

nav h2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav ul{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will vertically center your text without you having to guess the line height...

**[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rszc5/)**

Comment: That's a cool way to do it. I actually really like css tables. They're really good for lots of things.

Comment: Thanks, man! It's pretty handy to throw in a CSS table when you need it!